# How to disable "Automatically add invitations to my Google Calender" by using the API

Tags: security, google-calendar-api

In the Google calendar user interface, it is possible to disable "Automatic adding of invitations to my calendar" as can be found in [google's product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/JHEQkR4L1FQ).

However, can this setting also be done programmaticly by using the google calendar API? I would have expected to find this in the [google calendar API reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars).

Reason: My program is dynamicly creating/destroying new public accessable google calendars and I need to make sure that nobody can add events by just sending an email invitation to the corresponding calendar email address.